# Shader AOV while having a transparent shader assigned

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, shader-nodes

I am trying to get a texture as a [Shader AOV Output](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/output/aov.html) while having a transparent BSDF assigned to the object in Blender in EEVEE. But I'm unable to see anything in the AOV output. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell if you are doing anything wrong... should we say: yes, you have plugged this where it does not belong or that is in the wrong order...? You give us no information how you set it up. That's just a general remark for asking questions. However, in this case I can say, if the _Transparent BSDF_ is set to make the object completely invisible, then the AOV channel in the _Compositor_ won't show anything even if it is set up correctly because it is affected by the alpha transparency.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the reply! I have extracted AOV's for other objects with different shaders. My doubt was if i can extract an AOV somehow while using a transparent BSDF. I did see an output until i changed the blend mode of the shader to Alpha clip. As, you just clarified AOV's are also affected by the alpha of the material, that clears my doubt as well. Thank you.